# Is there an event or something i can use when a showdialogwindow is blocking the window i try to access

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, window, showdialog

I have 2 windows. Lets call them A and B.
A is opening B with a ShowDialog().
So I am opening B - When the user minimizes B or gets it into the back somehow and he tries clicking window A again its blocked (as it should be), but is there an Event that I can catch up onto when this happens ?

I am trying to achieve bringing the blocking window B into the front when hes trying to access window A with window B opened.

Codeexample:

Thats how Window A is opened from the Mainwindow

```
            WindowA windowA = new WindowA();

            windowA.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;

            windowA.Show();
            windowA.Activate();
```

And thats how Window B is opened

```
            WindowB windowB = new WindowB();
            windowB.Owner = this; //(this = windowA)
            windowB.ShowDialog();
```

Both windows have no special properties set except

```
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
```

Comment: It sounds like you're not setting B's `Owner` property to A?

Comment: I rechecked it but I already set the Owner before the ShowDialog()

Comment: So I guess we are talking about a modal dialog, right? Would you mind adding a [mcve]? So we can see how exactly your Dialog relates to the opening Form and what you are setting and what not?

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/sotestapp  I uploaded the testapplication here. You can just click threw the Middlebutton on the application -> then minimize Window B then open Window A again. Now Window A is blocking and i want to show B again when A is Blocking

Comment: @TannerHall: Don't upload your sample to an external site. Post it here.

Comment: @mm8 this will probably get hate, but I haven't found the possibility to upload a zip-file directly in here and even when I checked online for how to do that - everything i find is you can't and people said use dropbox etc.

Comment: You shouldn't upload a .zip file but edit your question to include code snipperts that make up a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @mm8 i edited my ticket  - thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to restore second window when it is minimized and user does click on first(blocked) window, then you can go this way(add this code to the `WindowB`):

```
public WindowB()
{
    PreviewMouseDown += WindowB_PreviewMouseDown;
    StateChanged += WindowB_StateChanged;
    InitializeComponent();
    LostMouseCapture += WindowB_LostMouseCapture;

}

private void WindowB_LostMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //You can also evaluate here a mouse coordinates.
    if (WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        CaptureMouse();
    }
}

private void WindowB_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (WindowState== WindowState.Minimized)
    {
        CaptureMouse();
    }
    else
    {
        ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }
}

private void WindowB_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    Debug.WriteLine("WindowB PreviewMouseDown");
}
```

So you have to start mouse capturing on second window on it being minimized, for if user does click on `WindowA` this can be handled on `WindowB`.
As window being minimized it going to lost a mouse capture(therefore you have to listen on `LostMouseCapture`), that you have to prevent.

Left mouse button down on `WindowA` does restore then`WindowB`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no managed event being raised when you click outside of a modal window but you should be able to handle this in the modal window using some p/invoke. Here is an example for you:

```
public sealed partial class ModalWindow : Window, IDisposable
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookDelegate lpfn, IntPtr hmod, int dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hHook, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hHook);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetCursorPos(out POINT lpPoint);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct POINT
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;

        public static implicit operator Point(POINT point)
        {
            return new Point(point.X, point.Y);
        }
    }

    public delegate IntPtr HookDelegate(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;
    private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    private HookDelegate mouseDelegate;
    private IntPtr mouseHandle;

    public ModalWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mouseDelegate = MouseHookDelegate;
        mouseHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, mouseDelegate, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
    }

    private IntPtr MouseHookDelegate(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (code < 0)
            return CallNextHookEx(mouseHandle, code, wParam, lParam);

        switch ((int)wParam)
        {
            case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                POINT lpPoint;
                GetCursorPos(out lpPoint);
                if (lpPoint.X < Left || lpPoint.X > (Left + Width) || lpPoint.Y < Top || lpPoint.Y > (Top + Height))
                {
                    //Outside click detected...
                }
                break;
        }

        return CallNextHookEx(mouseHandle, code, wParam, lParam);
    }

    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        Dispose();
        base.OnClosed(e);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (mouseHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(mouseHandle);
    }
}
```