# What is the event being called when you click outside the app current main window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Currently working on a c#/wpf program. 
When I click a certain button I show a new window on top and set it to the app current main window.

So when I click outside this main window, windows make the sound that I can't click outisde. Great!

I want to know what event is being called when this happen because sometime this window is not on top and in this case I want to put it back on top.

EDIT: I want to put it on top when it's also and background not necessary minimized.

Thank you.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55954502/7252182).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an event or something i can use when a showdialogwindow is blocking the window i try to access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55948944/is-there-an-event-or-something-i-can-use-when-a-showdialogwindow-is-blocking-the)

Comment: This solution work when the B window is minimized, but not when it's in background.